# How do I name the column resulting from a do-form transform using Julia DataFrames?

Tags: dataframe, julia

For reasons, I have to use the `do` form (block form?) of `DataFrames.transform`

```
df = DataFrame(:a => [i for i in 1:10])

transform(df) do d
  [d[i, :a] * 10 for i in 1:nrow(d)]
end

 Row │ a      x1
     │ Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────
   1 │     1     10
   2 │     2     20
   3 │     3     30
   . |     .     ..
```

and that's all good, but I'd like that new column to be called something else other than `x1`. I can't see an obvious way in the docs aside from renaming it post-hoc. Is there a way of coming out of the block with a named column (and possibly even more than one?) instead of it being named `xn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a `DataFrame` or a `NamedTuple`:

```
df = DataFrame(:a => [i for i in 1:10])

transform(df) do d
  (result=[d[i, :a] * 10 for i in 1:nrow(d)],)
end

transform(df) do d
  DataFrame(result=[d[i, :a] * 10 for i in 1:nrow(d)])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
df.something = map(eachrow(df)) do x
  x.a * 10
end
```

Result:

```
julia> df
10×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a      something
     │ Int64  Int64
─────┼──────────────────
   1 │     1         10
   2 │     2         20
   3 │     3         30
   4 │     4         40
   5 │     5         50
   6 │     6         60
   7 │     7         70
   8 │     8         80
   9 │     9         90
  10 │    10        100
```

Comment: I need to access rows by index, so I'd have to map over an integer range, but this could work, thanks! I was just hoping there was a way of doing it with `transform`.